# When we do cross validation what are we cross validating?

Tags: machine-learning, cross-validation

First the definition. Cross validation: With only the training dataset, we estimate what the test error would be.

Obviously we want to do whatever we can to get the **lowest** test error.
However, which of the following are we actually cross validating in this process?

- Feature selection within a model (eg. which features are important/have high variance/contributes to the model vs. which features are irrelevant and should not be included in the model)
- Model selection (pick between multiple models) (eg. logistic reg vs. random forest vs. XGBoost)
- Hyperparameter selection (within a model)
- All of the above

Answer (score 3):

There is no restriction, so it can be all of the above. However, it is usually expensive to do all and we choose the *most* important things to tune.

Comment: Perfect, and is there a systematic/rule-based way to determine what constitutes most important to least important? Or case-by-case.

Comment: I believe not (yet), thus the italic font. Yet, we have common sense, e.g. we don't do pixel (i.e. feature) selection in an image but perform experiments on the learning rates or filter size in conv nets.